# Bash one-liner to read stdin and print last 10 matches each for 2 separate patterns, without using tmp files / awk / perl / etc

Tags: bash

EDIT: Generally speaking, I'm asking for an elegant way to duplicate an input stream, process it with 2 or more sets of commands, then merge the output of these commands. Emphasis on elegant.

Real-world use case: In a CI pipeline, a `bash` script is doing `git fetch --tags` which outputs a long list of tags. The tags all look like `desktop-...` or `mobile-...`. We don't really need to see tags from months or years ago, so I'd like to avoid printing the whole list, and instead print just the last 10 (each) desktop and mobile tags. I can imagine a scenario where there would be more than 2 platforms, so in general case we would like to be able to filter an arbitrary number of groups of 10.

Rules:

- Has to be a neat and elegant **bash** one-liner, not a script (use some advanced bash features or (more or less common) helper utilities to reduce the amount of code)
- Should not use temporary files or something else that requires cleanup
- No piping to awk, perl or similar
- No complicated bash logic (e.g. counter variables and a `while read` loop)
- Has to work both in the terminal and when detached from a tty (like in the CI env)
- Has to match at least 2 patterns, and print 10 last results for each
- The results for each pattern should not be intermingled, but let's say this requirement is loose, as long as the solution allows to `| sort -V` the complete output as the last step
- Bonus points if the solution can be extended to 3+ patterns

For simplicity of testing, I deleted all the local tags, dumped the output of `git fetch --tags` to a file called tags, and am just using `cat tags` during my attempts. To make it easier for you to test possible solutions, here's a simple script that generates a reasonably looking mock input:

```
for ((i=0; i<100; ++i)); do echo "$((1+RANDOM/5000)).0.$((RANDOM/5000))"; done | sort -V | while read v; do [[ $((RANDOM%2)) == 1 ]] && echo -n "mobile-" || echo -n "desktop-"; echo $v; done >tags
```

Note: The solution shouldn't refer to the file directly. If it was ok, you could just `grep` it twice or more to get 10 matches of each pattern. But in the use case I described the command `git fetch --tags` runs only once (even if it was run more than once, it would output nothing on the second run, since the tags would already be fetched by the first run). So it's only allowed to use this input file once like so: `cat tags`. This is intended to emulate the real-world use case described above.

My best attempt so far:

```bash
cat tags | tee >(grep '\<desktop-' | tail -n 10) | grep '\<mobile-' | tail -n 10
```

The problem with the "desktop" process substitution is: its stdout is null, so the output is lost. All the examples of process substitution that I've seen redirect the output such commands to a file. I feel like there's gotta be some nice way to "merge" such output back into a single stream, but I couldn't find this way so far.

Solutions that produce the desired output but don't meet my rules for being neat and elegant (both of them are a bit long:

- Some typical imperative programming, the kind of code you would write if you were using a "real" programming language. It's not in the spirit of UNIX shell scripting, which is using pipes and standard commands, each doing one job (and do it well) to achieve the desired end result.

```bash
d=0; m=0; tac tags | while read l; do [[ $d -lt 10 && $l =~ ^desktop- ]] && { echo $l; let ++d; }; [[ $m -lt 10 && $l =~ ^mobile- ]] && { echo $l; let ++m; } done | sort -V
```

- Uses pipes and bash's process substituion, but uses a temporary file. "Proper" usage of temp files generally involves `mktemp`, cleaning up afterwards, handling abnormal script termination (using `trap` to do cleanup on SIGHUP/SIGINT).

```bash
cat tags | tee >(grep '\<mobile-' | tail -n 10 >mobile-tags) | grep '\<desktop-' | tail -n 10 && cat mobile-tags && rm -f mobile-tags
```

Comment: Are you trying to parse XML? If yes, there's better tools like `xmlstarlet` or `xmllint`

Comment: Cant do much without a complete sample of input and desired output.

Comment: @GillesQuénot Not parsing XML, I already mentioned that my input is a list of git tags, which look like `desktop-1.2.3` or `mobile-4.5.6`

Comment: @Nic3500 If you insist, run this to get a sample input to work with: `for ((i=19; i>0; --i)); do echo "desktop-$i.$((i/2)).0"; echo "mobile-$((i+5)).$((i/2+1)).0"; done >tags`
The following command produces the output I want to see - but only in an interactive shell, e.g. redirecting the output to a file will not produce the same result: `cat tags | tee >(grep '\<desktop-' | tail -n 10 >/dev/tty) | grep '\<mobile-' | tail -n 10`

Comment: Do you "accept" the use of `;` ?  Then it becomes quite simple, `grep pattern1 | sort | tail; grep pattern2 | sort | tail`.

Comment: @Nic3500 I can accept some usage of `;` as long as the solution is neat and concise. But in the actual use case the input comes from a command (`git fetch --tags`). For this puzzle, no temporary files are allowed. To allow easy testing of possible solutions, I offered an option to use a file with the input data. However you're not allowed to refer to the file in the solution more than once - the initial `cat tags` emulates the real-world scenario of this puzzle.

Comment: Temp files have issues: they must have unique names to avoid conflicts, and they have to be cleaned up afterwards. AFAIK file descriptors don't suffer from such issues, so by all means, use IO redirection. I was actually playing around with these quite a bit, trying to achieve the desired result, but it didn't work. When using process substitution, each instance is a subshell so runs in its own process and has its own file descriptors. There might be some way to set up subshells' FDs, but I'm quite a bit rusty on my low-level UNIX stuff...  Maybe I'm too fixated on process substitution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, got it this morning, `plumbing`:

the idea is to `dup()`licate the output on both `STDERR` and `STDOUT` with `tee` and parse it in //:

Here we go, could be a *one liner* as well, on multiline for readability:

```
git fetch --tags | tee /dev/stderr 2> >(
grep -w mobile   | tail -n10) 1> >(
grep -w desktop  | tail -n10)
```

Or with the help or your brilliant comments (kind of *brainstorming*):

```
git fetch --tags | tee  /dev/fd/{10,11,12} 10> >(
grep -w desktop  | tail -n 3) 11> >(
grep -w mobile   | tail -n 3) 12> >(
grep -w foobar   | tail -n 3) 1>/dev/null
```

Could be simplified as:

```
git fetch --tags | tee >(
grep -w mobile   | tail -n3) >(
grep -w desktop  | tail -n3) >(
grep -w foobar   | tail -n3) > /dev/null
```

Related: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution

Comment: First of all, the code works. It's kinda brilliant, but I am still trying to understand it 100%. I understand that `tee /dev/stderr` duplicates the input so it comes out on both stdout and stderr of tee. You redirect each one into a subshell using IO redirection and process substitution. So one subshell's stdin is `tee`'s stdout, and the other's is `tee`'s stderr. The thing I don't understand is that where does the subshell's stdouts go, and why. I don't fully understand the difference between `1> >(grep ...)` and if I would replace this with `| grep ...` or `| (grep ...)`...

Comment: If I do use a `|`, then the first subshell's (`grep mobile` one) output disappears. This is what I was experiencing in my experiments, because I was using a pipe after the `tee`. Can you pls explain what's going on here with the IO redirections?

Comment: I also noticed that the `2>&1` at the end is not needed. Outer `{}` along works, or `| cat`. With `2>/dev/null`, both desktop and mobile still appear. Or `>outfile` - both desktop and mobile results end up in the file. I am struggling to understand why is this so, logically it would seem that the `grep mobile` subshell would output to stderr. So far my guess is that in your `tee` command, the subshell's get different streams as their stdins, but both inherit the same `stdout` (the parent's stdout). But I don't really understand is why it is so, e.g. which part of bash's manpage explains that?

Comment: I also figured how to extend your solution to more than two filters. E.g. the following will print all tags that don't match desktop or mobile pattern, then 10 desktop ones and 10 mobiles ones: `cat tags | tee 3<&1 /dev/fd/2 /dev/fd/3 3> >(grep -Ewv 'desktop|mobile') 2> >(grep -w mobile   | tail -n10) > >(grep -w desktop  | tail -n10)`

One more thing I don't really get. The redirections in here are `3>... 2>... >...`. If I just change this to `>... 2>... 3>...`, then only the first one produces any output. Struggling to understand what's really going on here :D

Comment: So this general template seems to work, and its results don't change if the order of redirections is changed:
`cat tags | tee /dev/fd/{3,4,5,...} 3> >(filter1) 4> >(filter2) 5> >(filter3) ... >/dev/null`

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/736816/bash-io-redirection-with-tee-without-complicated-redirection-how-it-works

Comment: Added version without using `/dev/fd/{10,11,12}`

Comment: Heh, your latest version is the best so far, it works great and fits all of the requirements. So the trick is to do all the work in these subshells, and don't pipe `tee`'s stdout to a filter, but instead redirect it to `/dev/null`. If this is done, every subshell's output goes to the original stdout (for whatever reason...). Mosf of the examples on the topic of process substitution I found earlier had one or more filters as subshells (with output redirected to some file), and the final filter was tee's output piped to another command.

Comment: Something else I noticed. Example code: `printf '%s\n' $(seq 1 100) | tee >(head -n 2) >(tail -n 2) >/dev/null`
Sometimes it shows the expected 1 2 99 100, but more often than not something like 1 2 28 29. Perhaps `head` prints the two lines it was asked for, then closes it's stdin, and `tee` gets a "broken pipe" error when it tries to write further lines. Just guessing here. Workaround is to use `>(cat | head -n 2)`.

Comment: Found this topic discussed, I was almost right on the diagnosis: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16664257/misbehaving-head-with-redirection

Answer (score 1):

Using [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) and the good switches:

```
$ grep -Ewm20 'desktop|mobile' tags | sort
desktop-10.5.0
desktop-11.5.0
desktop-12.6.0
desktop-13.6.0
desktop-14.7.0
desktop-15.7.0
desktop-16.8.0
desktop-17.8.0
desktop-18.9.0
desktop-19.9.0
mobile-15.6.0
mobile-16.6.0
mobile-17.7.0
mobile-18.7.0
mobile-19.8.0
mobile-20.8.0
mobile-21.9.0
mobile-22.9.0
mobile-23.10.0
mobile-24.10.0
```

Comment: This produces the expected result only for this artificial input, which has desktop and mobile tags alternating one by one. In real life it will not be like this. Modify the command that produces the artificial input and it all falls apart. E.g. `for ((i=19; i>0; --i)); do echo "desktop-$i.$((i/2)).0"; echo "desktop-$((i+3)).$((i/2)).0"; echo "mobile-$((i+5)).$((i/2+1)).0"; done >tags` . Your solution then outputs 14 desktop tags and 6 mobile ones. I want 10 of each. I don't think `grep` alone can do that.

Comment: Then your question is wrong, edit your post with **required real sample input**

Comment: I've edited the post and included the updated script to generate the input data. I admit my initial mock data was not the best quality. As with any unit testing, you can't cover every possible input data. If the data used follows some patterns which don't actually match real-life data, an erroneous solution may pass the test. Hopefully my new set is better.

Comment: Thanks for introducing the `-m` option to `grep`, though - didn't know about this one.

Comment: Usually, the way to thanks people giving time and tips is to upvote... Moreover, was working with your original requirements

Comment: I don't mind to upvote, done. My original requirements didn't mention anywhere that the input data is constrained as "each desktop tag is followed by a mobile tag". This was a mere unfortunate limitation of my initial mock data script. The updated one generates much more random looking output which is not fully realistic but I guess should be good enough for this question.

Answer (score 1):

What about this one liner?

```
d=( $(grep desktop tags) ) m=( $(grep mobile tags) ); printf '%s\n' "${d[@]:0:10}" "${m[@]:0:10}" | sort -rV
```

Comment: This looks like it can do the job. I had to slightly adjust the command to give the output I expected to see, like so: `d=( $(grep desktop tags | tail -n 10) ) m=( $(grep mobile tags | tail -n 10) ); printf '%s\n' "${d[@]:0:10}" "${m[@]:0:10}"`

Comment: It's nice how `printf` can be used to implement something like `array.join('\n')` of most programming languages. Didn't know about that. From `help printf`: "The format is re-used as necessary to consume all of the arguments."

Comment: I have to say the idea to use arrays didn't come to my mind. I think arrays have always been my weakest skill in bash. Every time that I know that I should use an array for some task, I have to look up the manpage to refresh my memory on how to declare and access them :)

Comment: So far your solution is the best, temporary variables are much better than temporary files. Still, in a perfect world, you have to make sure that the variable names are unique (to not overwrite something else), and then it's not a bad idea to do cleanup when done (unset the variables). Obviously, there's much less chance to cause issues than when using temporary files. Still, a perfect solution wouldn't involve temporary variables or files. I just keep thinking that there's gotta be a way to do it with some weird combination of pipes, IO redirections, process substitutions and whatnot.

Comment: You could try using plumbing with file descriptors. Now need to `sleep(3600*8)`